# Android Animation Does Not ShowUp

Tags: android, animation

I was actually working up on an animation in my android application just to make it look more attractive. When i called it in my code it does not show up. Rather than the animation the activity that i called in my code after running the animation shows up. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView animationTarget = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_around_center_point);
    animationTarget.startAnimation(animation);


    Intent start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ApplicationFunctionalityStarting.class);
    startActivity(start);



}
```

What could be wrong here possibly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set Your animation to an animationListener and start the activity onAnimationEnd. Here is an example for an AnimationListener:

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/09/handle-animation-event.html